# Failing to perform an UPDATE with JOIN in Spring + JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to perform an UPDATE using a project with:
- Jdk 11
- Springboot 2.2.3
- Mysql 8.0.18

This is my query (in repository):

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE VC SET bulkId = :bulkId WHERE vId = :vId AND user.ttt=:TTT")
    void updateBulkId(String bulkId, String vId, String TTT);
```

This is my VC model:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter
public class VC
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String bulkId;

    private String vId;

}
```

and this is my User model:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter
public class User
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String ttt;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set bulkId='123ABC' where vId='1' and ttt='123'' at line 1
```

I think that for some reason JPA is failing to join the two tables (VC and User).

Thanks for the help

Comment: There could be an an extra quote in the `ttt` value.  You may need to escape it.

Comment: @Sid this is the closing quote of the mysql error message. The opening quote is just before "set bulkId=...". Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a subquery:

```
@Query("UPDATE VC SET bulkId = :bulkId WHERE vId = :vId 
  AND user.id in (
    select u.id
    from User u
    where u.ttt=:TTT"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Mental sanity restored :D

Answer (score 0):

## Update - Use Join

You've an error in your JPQL. You need to refer to related Entity using itself as below and add `@Param`:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying 
@Query("UPDATE VC vc JOIN vc.user u SET vc.bulkId = :bulkId WHERE vc.vId = :vId AND u.ttt=:TTT")
void updateBulkId(@Param("bulkId")String bulkId, @Param("vId")String vId, @Param("TTT")String TTT);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution, but it is not working in my case. I still get the same error. Is there anything else I can try? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Also, you can avoid tu use @ Param if the name of the variable is the same as the variable in your @ Query

Comment: I doubt it.  The error clearly says that there is an SQL error.  @LucaAtWork, can you share the generated query?

Comment: @Sid the problem is that I'm using a non primary key field (ttt) in my WHERE clause. If I use a primary key field (like vc.user.id) then it works :/
Another working option is to use native sql (nativeQuery=true), but I'd like to stick with JPA as long as possible.

Comment: Use Join as above since `ttt` isn't a column in VC **table**.

Comment: @Mansoor thanks for the help, but I get: "Expecting 'set', found 'JOIN' "